# CentOS 6.8 install rabbitmq 3.7.4

Tags: centos, erlang, rabbitmq, centos6

I'm trying to install RabbitMQ 3.7.4 on CentOS 6.8. Currently I have installed Erlang 20 following instruction from https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/HOWTO/INSTALL.md , but when I tried :

```
sudo yum install https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/all/rabbitmq-server/3.7.4/rabbitmq-server-3.7.4-1.el6.noarch.rpm
```

it doesn't detect the Erlang 20. Instead it searched for the available Erlang package from my EPEL, which is the R14B, and wont install since it is lower than the minimum Erlang version requirements. How do I fix this and install RabbitMQ?

Comment: Probably might get more help on one of the linux sites. This is an OS-specific issue, not necessarily a RabbitMQ issue. You'll most likely need to add a repo to yum.

Comment: Have you tried following the directions on installing Erlang? They are at the bottom of this page. https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Installation instructions at https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang/

### Installation using repository

#### 1. Adding repository entry

To add Erlang Solutions repository (including our public key for verifying signed package) to your system, call the following commands:

```
wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
```

#### Alternatively: adding the repository entry manually

RPM packages are signed. To add Erlang Solutions key, execute command:

```
rpm --import https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/rpm/erlang_solutions.asc
```

Add the following lines to some file in "/etc/yum.repos.d/":

```
[erlang-solutions]
name=CentOS $releasever - $basearch - Erlang Solutions
baseurl=https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/rpm/centos/$releasever/$basearch
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/rpm/erlang_solutions.asc
enabled=1
```

#### 2. Adding repository with dependencies

Packages requires some packages that are not present in standard repository. Please ensure that EPEL respository is enabled.

#### 3. Installing Erlang

Call the following command to install the "erlang" package:

```
sudo yum install erlang
```

or this command to install the "esl-erlang" package:

```
sudo yum install esl-erlang
```

Please refer to the [FAQ](https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang/) for the difference between those versions. Your erlang will be kept up to date either way.

Comment: thanks. i was following the instruction from digitalocean which installs erlang from EPEL repo. it works after switching to erlang solutions repo